# Input List of Items, Output List of ItemIDs

Tags: python, list

I currently has an Excel file with one column for ItemID and one column for ItemName in this style:

```
ItemID, ItemName
2, Apple
4, Orange
5, Pear
6, Banana
15, Kiwi
```

I am open to converting this data in to whatever format would be easiest, but I need an explanation of how to go about that conversion.

I want to pass a list like this:
['Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana']

And have it output a list like this:
[2,5,6]

I have looked at doing this with sqlite3 but I can't find how to pass a whole list as input and I can't find an easy way to convert my Excel file into some sort of .sql or .db file that sqlite3 could dig through.  I really don't care what sort of file (or even file-type item) I end up having to convert my Excel file into, I just want the look up process to be efficient.

EDIT:
In the actual case I'm working with there are about 8800 items.  Also, each is unique such that ItemID is unique and ItemName is unique.  That said, some item names are similar with just an extra word added on the end such as 'Orange Small' and 'Orange Large'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically the `csv` module version of @inspectorG4dget's answer.  First, save your file in `csv` format from Excel, producing something like this:

```
ItemID, ItemName
2, Apple
4, Orange
5, Pear
6, Banana
15, Kiwi
```

Since you say that each ItemName is unique, we can use a dictionary to store the data.  In python 2.7, and using a helper function like inspectorG4dget's getIDs:

```
import csv

with open("itemids.csv","rb") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, skipinitialspace=True)
    fp.readline() # skip header
    name_to_id = {name: int(id) for id, name in reader}

def getIDs(name_to_id, names):
    return [name_to_id[name] for name in names]
```

We can build a dictionary and access it:

```
>>> name_to_id
{'Orange': 4, 'Kiwi': 15, 'Pear': 5, 'Apple': 2, 'Banana': 6}
>>> getIDs(name_to_id, ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana"])
[2, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I ended up using this method with two modifications - I set delimiter to "\t" and used a tab separated rather than comma separated file (because some of my item names have a comma in them) and then I stored the results as a string like so: idlist = getIDs(name_to_id, modlist) (where modlist is the name of the list I had made earlier in the style ['Orange', 'Apple', 'Pear']

This worked nicely and I can't notice any real lag time while it searches and spits out the idlist list so I think this solution works well for the scale I'm working with.

Comment: @Qanthelas: sure, tab separation is fine.  But if your values are correctly quoted -- e.g. `17, "Orange, fresh"` -- comma separation will work too.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have this as a textfile, which looks like this:

```
2, Apple
4, Orange
5, Pear
6, Banana
15, Kiwi
```

Then you could do:

```
def readFile(fpath):
    answer = {}
    with f as open(fpath):
        for line in f:
            id, name = line.split(', ')
            id = int(id)
            name = name.strip()
            answer[name] = id
    return answer

def getIDs(names, nameIDs):
    return [nameIDs[name] for name in names]

def main():
    nameIDs = readfile('path/to/file')
    names = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana']
    ids = getIDs(names, nameIDs)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That certainly gets points for being an easy solution.  It did make me remember a few details that I should probably post, so I edited my question.  For one, would this method be feasible on a textfile with around 9000 entries?

Comment: This would handle 9000 entries easily

Comment: 9000 entries should be just over half an MB

Comment: Fair enough, I think my attempts to get in to sqlite were a serious case of over-engineering.  I like the .csv approach, but you showed that it is easily feasible to handle this data with some functions and not worry about trying to bring in a database parser.  Thanks!

Comment: I'd give you a cookie/free internet/upvote/whatever they give on this site, but sadly I apparently can't because I'm a newbie here :(

Comment: I can finally upvote now so I've upvoted this (but you can keep the thought-that-counts-cookie :P)